# Fallo en Política de Seguridad de Contenido (CSP)

Tags: html, seguridad, csp

Estuve leyendo [este interesante artículo](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp) y tratando de poner en práctica algunas políticas de seguridad en mi sitio.

Quiero permitir solamente los archivos `.js` que se encuentran en la ruta: `midominio.com/src/js`.

Tengo declarada la CSP del siguiente modo:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
default-src 'none'; 
img-src 'self';
connect-src 'self' 
    https://www.midominio.com/src/php 
    https://www.google-analytics.com
    https://stats.g.doubleclick.net
    https://analytics.google.com;
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
    https://www.midominio.com/src/js 
    https://www.googletagmanager.com 
    https://use.fontawesome.com 
    https://cdn.polyfill.io 
    https://code.jquery.com 
    https://www.google-analytics.com          
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
    https://www.midominio.org 
    https://cdn.jsdelivr.net 
    https://use.fontawesome.com;
font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
    https://use.fontawesome.com;
      ">
```

En un archivo intento incluir un archivo Javascript de mi directorio `js`, pero me lo está bloqueando con este mensaje:

> Refused to load https://www.midominio.com/src/js/mi-archivo.js?0.04
> because it does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content
> Security Policy.

Se supone que la directiva es la correcta. No entiendo por qué no funciona.

Comment: No estoy seguro que se deba usar un tag HTML para esto. No soy experto pero siempre los he configurado como cabeceras (`header`), mas precisamente con un `.htaccess`. Si te interesa puedo ofrecerte una respuesta utilizando esta forma.

Comment: @Msrcos, me interesa. Me parece que `.htaccess` es más confiable. Opté por hacerlo en el HTML basándome en un ejemplo que vi en otro sitio. Estoy haciendo pruebas y por momentos funciona, pero a veces al mover archivos de carpeta en las pruebas falla esta directiva u otra. No sé si es un problema de caché o que no me aclaro con las directivas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas `Apache` y has activado [`mod_headers`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html), entonces, usando `.htaccess` podrías aplicarlo así:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://www.midominio.com/src/php https://www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://analytics.google.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.midominio.com/src/js https://www.googletagmanager.com https://use.fontawesome.com https://cdn.polyfill.io https://code.jquery.com https://www.google-analytics.com style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.midominio.org https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://use.fontawesome.com; font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://use.fontawesome.com;"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: De entrada te agradezco por la sugerencia de hacerlo vía `.htaccess`. Lo he hecho y admite las directivas. Ya no bloquea el archivo `.js`, pero sí me bloquea un archivo `.php` que uso en una petición Ajax y me arroja tres errores: `[Error] Origin https://midominio.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.midominio.com/src/php/mi-action.php?mm=03&dd=10 due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://midominio.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (mi-action.php line 0)`

Comment: Como se puede ver más arriba, yo he admitido `connect-src 'self' https://www.midominio.com/src/php`, por lo que no entiendo este nuevo error. ¿O acaso debo poner la directiva `connect-src` en un archivo `.htaccess` de la carpeta `src/php`?

Comment: ... *¿O acaso debo poner la directiva connect-src en un archivo .htaccess de la carpeta src/php?* ... Lo he hecho y tampoco funciona...

Comment: @A.Cedano ahora has vuelto mas restrictivo el acceso a tus recursos y el navegador ahora require las [políticas de mismo origen](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Same-origin_policy). Podes solucionarlo estableciendo las reglas con `PHP` o también en el `.htaccess`. Si queres agrego en mi respuesta una solución a este problema... o podes crear una nueva pregunta.

Comment: daré esta por solucionada y abriré una nueva pregunta, dado que es un problema nuevo. Gracias.

Comment: He abierto [una nueva pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/419418/29967) con el nuevo problema. Gracias por tu ayuda.