# Error "Origin is not allowed" con un script de mi propio dominio aplicando CSP mediante .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, seguridad, csp

Tenía un problema con un archivo Javascript aplicando Política de Seguridad de Contenido (CSP) y pude resolverlo gracias a [esta respuesta de @Marcos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/419379/29967) en la pregunta [Fallo en Política de Seguridad de Contenido (CSP)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/419365/29967).

Ahora me está bloqueando otro archivo, en este caso es un `.php` que uso para gestionar una petición Ajax.

Me está dando estos tres errores en consola:

```
[Error] Origin https://midominio.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. 
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.midominio.com/src/php/mi-action.php?mm=03&dd=10 due to access control checks.  
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://midominio.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
(mi-action.php line 0)
```

Este es mi código en el archivo `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://www.midominio.com/src/src/php/ https://www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://analytics.google.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.midominio.com/src/src/js/ https://www.googletagmanager.com https://use.fontawesome.com https://cdn.polyfill.io https://code.jquery.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://demo.creativebulma.net; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.midominio.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://use.fontawesome.com; font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://use.fontawesome.com;"
</IfModule>
```

¿Cómo podría resolver este nuevo problema?

Comment: ¿Probaste con `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?

Comment: @anythingg estaba tratando de aplicar [lo indicado aquí](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp)... ¿dónde debería probar? No tengo experiencia con esto, primero lo estaba haciendo en el HTML y Marcos me sugirió que lo haga desde `.htaccess`, lo cual me pareció más sensato y más seguro. ¿Se puede aplicar `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` también en ese bloque? Tampoco entiendo por qué me bloquea un script que está en mi propio dominio.

Comment: ¿Si añades `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://tudominio.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS"` en el `.htaccess` sigue sin funcionar?

Comment: @anythingg correcto, funciona tal cual has sugerido, sin embargo, si pongo `www.` no funciona.

Comment: En resumidas cuentas, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` hace que tu dominio acepte peticiones dese un dominio en específico (o desde cualquiera si es que así lo prefieres), pero NO cuenta los subdominios, tienes que hacer `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.tudominio.com" Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS"`

Comment: Gracias @anythingg. Realmente lo que quiero es dar seguridad al sitio, admitiendo explícitamente los scripts que quiero que se ejecuten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes habilitarlo para:

- Cualquier origen:

  ```
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  ```
- Un origen específico:

  ```
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.midominio.com/
  ```

Tu `.htaccess` podría quedar así:

#### Ejemplo:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.midominio.com/"
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://www.midominio.com/src/src/php/ https://www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://analytics.google.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.midominio.com/src/src/js/ https://www.googletagmanager.com https://use.fontawesome.com https://cdn.polyfill.io https://code.jquery.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://demo.creativebulma.net; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.midominio.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://use.fontawesome.com; font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://use.fontawesome.com;"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ahora me funciona, **pero sólo si quito `www.`**, poniéndolo con `www.`  no funciona. Ha quedado así: `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://midominio.com/"` y ahora me admite el script `.php` Intuí lo de `www.` por los errores `1` y `3` en la pregunta. No entiendo por qué admite las peticiones así, espero que no dé problemas más adelante.

Comment: @A.Cedano deberías forzar todos los enlaces o con `www.` o sin `www.`, en `SEO` los enlaces son distintos (_salvo que utilices [`canonical`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls?hl=es)_), ya que se considera `www.dominio.com` un subdominio de `dominio.com`.

Comment: me parece que eso ya lo había hecho, pero en el dominio principal. Deberé revisar porque este código realmente está en una sub-carpeta del dominio principal.