# Cómo puedo evitar que otra página haga curl a mi sitio web?

Tags: php, curl, hosting

Resulta qué hay una página que utiliza un script php CURL para obtener un dato específico de mi sitio web.
Es posible bloquear esto, o bueno bloquear las solicitudes desde ese dominio en específico?
Tengo cloudflare, quizás me pueda dar herramientas para bloquear dominios?
O cuál sería la manera más efectiva de bloquear esta acción?

Comment: puedes bloquearlos mediantes los corp, solo tendrias que configurarlos

Comment: Por seguridad, deberías definir una política CSP (Content Security Policy). Lo más simple sería hacerlo desde `.htaccess`. En esas reglas puedes definir qué archivos/recursos tienen permiso para ciertas funciones, bloqueando aquellos que no tenga permisos, incluso si son de tu propia web. Revisa [este artículo sobre CSP](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp) y  [la respuesta de @Marcos a un caso concreto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/419379/29967), en la que hay un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo vía `.htaccess`.